# JQ How to add a node to a complete tree

Tags: arrays, json, variables, iteration, jq

Adding a field to a tree is straightforward:

```
echo '{ "a": "b" }' | jq '.'
{
  "a": "b"
}
echo '{ "a": "b" }' | jq '. + { c: "d" }'
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

But adding a field to an existing object does not work as was expected, by displaying only the modified subtree:

```
echo '{ "e": { "f": "g" } }' | jq '.' 
{
  "e": {
    "f": "g"
  }
}
echo '{ "e": { "f": "g" } }' | jq '.e + { h: "i" }' 
{
  "f": "g",
  "h": "i"
}
```

Tried various workarounds but none gave what was needed :

```
echo '{ "e": { "f": "g" } }' | jq '. as $k | .e + { h: "i" } | $k + .'
{
  "e": {
    "f": "g"
  },
  "f": "g",
  "h": "i"
}

echo '{ "e": { "f": "g" } }' | jq '. as $k | .e + { h: "i" } | $k + .e'
{
  "e": {
    "f": "g"
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "e": {
    "f": "g",
    "h": "i"
  }
}
```

Can somebody show me the errors of my ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intention is just to append an element to an object, it would be better to use `+=` as

```
jq '.e += { "h" : "i" }'
```

In action,

```
echo '{ "e": { "f": "g" } }' | jq '.e += { "h" : "i" }'
{
  "e": {
    "f": "g",
    "h": "i"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.